# Java - How to instantiate inner class with reflection?

Tags: java, android, reflection

I have been having problems with the instantiating the inner class using reflection. Heres an example.

```
public final class Cow {

    public Cow (Bufallo flying, Horse swimming, int cowID, int numCows) {
        //This is where the part I really dont know what the cow is doing
    }

    public Bull eatGrass(String grassName, AngusCattle farmName, JerseyCattle farmName){
        Ox newBreed = new Ox(australiaFarm, somewhereOutThere);
        //Something that has to do with cow eating grass
        return Bull;
    }

    private static final class Ox extends BigHorns {

        public Ox (AngusCattle farmName, ChianinaOx farmName) {
            //Something about mating
        }

    }

}
```

all I want is to get the constructor or just instantiate the inner class. My code so far...

```
CowManager cowManager = (CowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.COW_SERVICE);
final Class MainCowClass  = Class.forName(cowManager.getClass().getName());
final Class[] howManyCows = MainCowClass.getDeclaredClasses();
Class getCow = null;
for (int i=0; i < howManyCows.length; i++) {
    if (! howManyCows[i].getName().equals("Cow$Ox")) {
        continue;
    }
    getCow = Class.forName(howManyCows[i].getName());
}
Constructor createCow = getCow.getDeclaredConstructor();
```

as of the moment I cant seem to find the constructor of ox inside the cow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first access the inner class by doing something like below

```
// Straightforward parent class initializing
Class<?> cowClass = Class.forName("com.sample.Cow");
Object cowClassInstance = cowClass.newInstance();

// attempt to find the inner class
Class<?> oxClass = Class.forName("com.sample.Cow$Ox");

// Now find the instance of the inner class, you may need to pass in arguments for the constructor
Constructor<?> oxClassContructor = oxClass.getDeclaredConstructor(cowClass);

// initialize the inner instance using the parent class's (cow's) instance
Object oxClassInstance = oxClassContructor.newInstance(cowClassInstance);
```

**Edit**

The constructors should look like below

```
// define the type of args that the constructor requires.
oxClass.getDeclaredConstructor(com.sample.AngusCattle.class, com.sample.ChianinaOx.class);
// now init the constructor with the required args.
Object oxClassInstance = oxClassContructor.newInstance(cowClassInstance, angusCattleClassInstance, chianinaOxClassInstance);
```

Comment: I get  java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.sample.Cow has no zero argument constructor when I make the cowClassInstance.

Comment: I also want to add, why do I have to create a new instance when I already created a new instance `CowManager cowManager = (CowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.COW_SERVICE);`? Does that mean that I have to create a new instance? or replace the code with your code?

Comment: `no zero argument` error means you are not passing in the required args to initialize the constructor. I mentioned it in the comments. And no, if you already have the instance of the class, then you dont need to create a new instance.